# Regex for 'X.XX' or 'X'. or 'X.X'?

Tags: regex, decimal

I want to develop a regex with allowed numbers:

```
''
'1'
'1.'
'1.0'
'1.00'
'9.99'
'10.00'
'99.99'
```

So far I built:

```
^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

but testing it on http://regexpal.com/ revealed I cannot do 'x.' test case.

How can I modify my regex to accompany this test case?

Comment: What about 00.1 and dot alone?

Comment: All we know is that you want to match the 8 cases you've listed, and that `^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` does *not* meet your requirements. `^(|1|1\.|1\.0|1\.00|9\.99|10\.00|99\.99)$` meets your requirements as you've stated them so far. I presume that isn't what you're looking for, which means you'll need to state the problem more clearly. Do you want to disallow more than two consecutive digits? And why is the empty string acceptable? Describe precisely in English what you want to match, and you'll be halfway to writing the corresponding regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `\d{0,2}` instead of `\d{1,2}` in your group.

Also, the dot needs to be escaped: `\.`.